# Using Castle Windsor in Unit Test Class

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, castle-windsor

I'm a noob with Castle Windsor. I'm building an application that uses Entity Framework 6 and Castle Windsor, with an MSTest Unit Test class. My application has a class in it that implements `IWindsorInstaller`. My unit test class looks like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class DatabaseTests {

    static readonly WindsorContainer Container = new WindsorContainer();

    public DatabaseTests() {
        Container.Install( FromAssembly.This() );
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void FirstTest() {
        // Test statements
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void SecondTest() {
        // Test statements
    }

    // Other tests
}
```

There is also an installer class in the unit tests project that looks like this:

```
public class TestsInstaller : IWindsorInstaller {
    public void Install( IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store ) {
        container.Install( new RecipeManager.RepositoriesInstaller() );
    }
}
```

When I go to the Unit Test Session window & try to run all tests, the first one succeeds, and I get this stack trace for the rest:

> Unable to create instance of class UnitTests.DatabaseTests. Error: Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentRegistrationException: Component RecipeManager.DAL.CategoryRepository could not be registered. There is already a component with that name. Did you want to modify the existing component instead? If not, make sure you specify a unique name..
>       at Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Naming.DefaultNamingSubSystem.Register(IHandler handler)
>      at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.AddCustomComponent(ComponentModel model)
>      at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Register(IRegistration[] registrations)
>      at Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Register(IRegistration[] registrations)
>      at RecipeManager.RepositoriesInstaller.Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store) in C:\Users\Tony\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\RecipeManager\ManageRecipes\RepositoriesInstaller.cs:line 10
>      at Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Install(IWindsorInstaller[] installers, DefaultComponentInstaller scope)
>      at Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Install(IWindsorInstaller[] installers)
>      at UnitTests.TestsInstaller.Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store) in C:\Users\Tony\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\RecipeManager\UnitTests\TestsInstaller.cs:line 8
>      at Castle.Windsor.Installer.AssemblyInstaller.Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
>      at Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Install(IWindsorInstaller[] installers, DefaultComponentInstaller scope)
>      at Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Install(IWindsorInstaller[] installers)
>      at UnitTests.DatabaseTests..ctor() in C:\Users\Tony\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\RecipeManager\UnitTests\DatabaseTests.cs:line 17

If I run the unit tests one at a time, they all succeed. I intend to build lots of tests, so I'd really rather be able to run them all at once.  How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm wondering if using Castle to handle your dependency injection for testing is actually a bad idea.   1) It violates self-documentation principle for unit tests, since dependencies are now hidden, and 2) if you change your dependencies, your code will still compile, potentially leaving code uncovered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your test class, create a field.

```
private WindsorContainer Container;
```

(replace the existing static field.)

Then, add this to your test class:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void SetUp()
{
    Container = new WindsorContainer();
    // register your dependencies
}

[TestCleanup]
public void Cleanup()
{
    Container.Dispose();
}
```

`[TestInitialize]` runs before every test, `[TestCleanup]` after every test.
That way you're not reusing the same container for every test and trying to re-register the same dependencies with that container. Before every single test is run you'll be creating a new container. If you need the same dependencies for every test you can register them in `Setup()`. Or you can register them in the test methods if needed.

Comment: I was just click `post your answer` when i say yours pop up. No fake point for me and some fake points for you

Comment: I actually don't know what that means. We get points for this?

Answer (score 1):

To upgrade a bit on this answer:
I created a Base RepositoryTest class which contained the Windsor Container logic. That class became the root of all Unit Test classes.

```
public abstract class RepositoryTestBase
{
    private static IWindsorContainer windsorContainer { get; set; }
    private static IMapper mapper { get; set; }

    protected static IWindsorContainer WindsorContainer
    {
        get
        {
            if (windsorContainer == null)
            {
                WindsorContainerManager.ConfigureWindsor(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
                windsorContainer = WindsorContainerManager.Container;
            }
            return windsorContainer;
        }
    }

    protected IMapper Mapper
    {
        get
        {
            if (mapper == null)
            {
                mapper = WindsorContainer.Resolve<IMapper>();
            }
            return mapper;
        }
    }

    public static T GetResolved<T>()
    {
        return WindsorContainer.Resolve<T>();
    }
}

    [TestFixture, Category("UnitTest")]
public class AccountRepositoryTests : RepositoryTestBase
{
    private IAccountRepository accountRepo = GetResolved<IAccountRepository>();
    private IContactRepository contactRepo = GetResolved<IContactRepository>();
```